# Getting newConnectionerror [Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None,redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken'NewConnectionError']

Tags: python, appium, robotframework, appium-android

Description
Trying to install the apk in physical device connected via usb
Developer options and usb debugging is on

NOTE
If application is already install able to open it but not able install if it is not present in device

IDE Pycharm
Robot framework using appium library

**Error:**

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connect
ion.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000249284D5180>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target 
machine actively refused it')': /wd/hub/session
```

**code**

```
commonActions.robot file
```

**Settings**

```
Documentation   Simple example using AppiumLibrary
Library         AppiumLibrary
Resource        ../../../app/config/env.robot
```

**Keywords**

```
Open Shaadi Application
#Install App  app_path=${APP_PATH}  appPackage=${APP_PACKAGE}
#Install App  ${APP_PATH}  ${APP_PACKAGE}
Open Application  http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
...  automationName=${AUTOMATION_NAME}  platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}  
platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}
...  app=${APP}  appPackage=${APP_PACKAGE}  appActivity=${APP_ACTIVITY}
```

[image]

Comment: @Kris. Please remove image. We don't need duplicates.